# xCode Objective C: Tapping UITableViewCells without indexPath.row

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if (indexPath.row == 0) {
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"hello" sender:self];
}
if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"hello1" sender:self];
}
```

This is the method I used to perform segues to go to the viewcontroller specified. However, I have implemented a search bar. The searchbar filters certain cells and reorders them. Because of this, different cells direct to a different view controller. If I search "hello1" in my search bar, it will show "hello1" as the first in the tableview, and will not show "hello". But since "hello" is set to indexPath.row == 0, tapping "hello1" in the app will perform the "hello" segue, and not the "hello1" segue. How can I fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

My searchBar code:

```
 -(void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
NSLog(@"clicked!");
if ([searchText length] == 0) {
    [_results removeAllObjects];
    [_results addObjectsFromArray:_testphrases];
} else {
    [_results removeAllObjects];
    for (NSString * string in _testphrases) {
        NSRange r = [string rangeOfString:searchText options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
                [_results addObject:string];
            }
        }

    }
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

(_results is _resultsArray, _testphrases is _masterArray)

New searchbar code:

```
-(void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSLog(@"clicked!");
    if ([searchText length] == 0) {
        [_results removeAllObjects];
        [_results addObjectsFromArray:_testphrases];
    } else {
        [_results removeAllObjects];
        for (NSDictionary * string in _testphrases) {
            for (NSString *key in string) {
                NSString *value = [string objectForKey:key];
            NSRange r = [value rangeOfString:searchText options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
                [_results addObject:string];
            }}
        }

    }
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

This is what it looks like when a search happens:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvZps.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stick to the MVC pattern you won't have this problem. What you need to do is have an array of objects for datasource of your table. This way, you can reference the object's name/id instead of the indexPath.row.

Something like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   Object *object = [_filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:object.segueId sender:self];
}
```

**EDIT**: It is difficult to help you since you do not give enough information/codes on your implementation. So let me just add an example of how to accomplish this.

- Create 2 mutablearrays. masterArray and resultsArray. masterArray would be our tableview main datasource. And resultsArray is when user searched something.
- Populate masterArray with custom object, or simply dictionary. For example:

  **[_masterArray addObject:@{@"title":@"First Item", @"segueID":@"hello"}];
  [_masterArray addObject:@{@"title":@"Second Item", @"segueID":@"hello1"}];**

Here you specify which segue you want to tie to which item.

- When user search, resultArray should be a filtered result of _masterArray hence resultArray contain a subset of masterArray which is then displayed in the table.
- Then in didSelect delegate of tableview, you can then get the selected object and its corresponding segueID to performSegue with.

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSDictionary *obj = [_resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:[obj objectForKey:@"segueID"] sender:self];
}

**EDIT2**: How to populate cell with data from array:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellID = @"yourCellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];

    }
    if ([resultsArray count]>0) {
    NSDictionary *item = [_resultsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.titleLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"title"];
    } else {
    NSDictionary *item = [_masterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.titleLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"title"];
    }



    return cell;
}
```

**EDIT 3**: What you want to do is get the value directly for key title and not loop through the keys. THis should work:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in _testphrases) {
            NSString *value = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];
            NSRange r = [value rangeOfString:searchText options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
                [_results addObject:dict];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how I can use this for my specific project?

Comment: I am not sure how you setup your cell and how your datasource looks like?

Comment: -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        
    }
    if([results count] > 0 && [results count] > indexPath.row){
    cell.textLabel.text = [results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        
    }
    return cell;
    
                           
    
}

Comment: can you also post all the other tableview delegates codes. and how you decide which data goes to which segue?

Comment: Add the codes in your question above (by using edit).

Comment: I use the storyboard to create the segues, the segues aren't programmatically created. The segues are set from table view to specified viewcontroller with a different identifier.

Comment: Any help with that?

Comment: When I use your code (turning my masterArray into nsmutablearray) the whole tableview becomes empty. How do I populate the tableview with text from this array?

Comment: @Ace See my EDIT2.

Comment: Again, nothing in tableview gets populated. I think the problem has to do with the masterArray nsmutablearray because when I NSLOG it, i get NULL back. Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Nevermind, just fixed it. My tableView is now populated and works with segues, however, when I search in the searchbar it gives me a sigbrt error with Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI rangeOfString:options:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Comment: for (NSString * string in _testphrases)  is wrong because content of _testphrases is NSDictionary not NSString. You should do (NSDictionary *dict in _testphrases), then get the string inside the for loop from each dictionary.

Comment: Fixed it, however, now another problem arises. Now when I search something I get multiple duplicate rows. I should be only getting one row per result, but I get multiple. The new code I used for the searchbar is in my new edit.

Comment: See EDIT3. Bare in mind this has now become totally out of topic from the original question.